# IEEE 802.11 Wi-Fi Radar

Tags: networking, security, network-monitor, wifi, network-administration

I'm frequently finding myself managing (and troubleshooting) an increasing number of networks that are (more or less) overrun with scores of ***2.4GHz; 802.11; Wireless Access Points;*** and (for the most part) ***mobile Wi-Fi devices.***

What would make my life easier is if I had a ***Kismet/Airodump style*** ***device and/or application*** that could help me to quickly ***discover*** which ***local Wi-Fi devices*** are within range (pretty standard so far, but here comes the challenge) and ***pinpoint (or approximate) the locations*** ***of arbitrary mobile network hosts*** in 3D-Space, by ***tracing the signals*** (that correspond to the ***unique*** ***MACs/BSSIDs***) back to their individual ***Wireless*** ***Network Interface Cards.***

---

In laymen's terms:
***A system for detecting the presence, direction, and distance of local Wi-Fi Devices.***
Just like a RADAR, or a metal detector, or a geiger counter.. you get the idea..

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice idea. If you now could let us also know what OS that detector should run on? From the topic, certainly a mobile one, but which?

Comment: @Izzy I'm not sure if it even exists at the moment.. or does it? I would take whatever is available and adapt it to my purpose at this point to be honest.. ;p But any modern Unix based OS would be a good idea: GNU/Linux, Android, iOS, OS X.. Any of these platforms would be fantastic.

Comment: Even going by the same name: [Wifi Radar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=girsas.wifiradar) for Android :)

Comment: @Izzy Hmm.. Sort of.. I actually have that already (and a few other attempts, ie. WiFiFoFum) on my Nexus|5. I think I'll probably end up having to build it myself from scratch to get what I want. :(

Comment: I have not tried it, so I only saw what its app description claimed. And according to that it should come pretty close. If it really does, consider [answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) describing how it matches and where it fails. Of course this requires more matches than failures – so it should really be close and just missing "minor things". Otherwise include it with your question and point out what you miss.